# Using Go beta releases with GitHub Actions

Tags: go, github-actions

Is it possible to use preview releases of the Go language with GitHub Actions?

Currently there is a 1.18 beta out and I'd like to start using some of the new changes in my projects already.

Comment: You can create action that customizes runner and installs whatever software you need. See [Customizing GitHub-hosted Runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/customizing-github-hosted-runners).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's not yet available through that action, but you can always install it manually.

Here's an example:

```
name: Golang

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.17.5
      - name: Install beta version
        run: |
          go install golang.org/dl/go1.18beta1@latest
          go1.18beta1 download
          cp $(which go1.18beta1) $(which go)
          go version
```